# How to get the first element of LinqToEntities result?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the first element of the LinqToEntities request.

Here is my code:

```
var para = (from param in context.Parameters
            where param.Code == paramCode
            select param.ValueDecimal);
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

```
**Edit:**
```

Thanks for your responses. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) methods:

```
var para = (from param in context.Parameters
            where param.Code == paramCode
            select param.ValueDecimal).First();
```

`First` will throw an exception if the `Enumerable` is empty.

```
var para = (from param in context.Parameters
            where param.Code == paramCode
            select param.ValueDecimal).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

`FirstOrDefault` returns the first element in the list or `null` if the list has no elements.

```
var para = (from param in context.Parameters
            where param.Code == paramCode
            select param.ValueDecimal).FirstOrDefault();
```